# Python response to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I have an AJAX request to my Python file like so

```
$ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: " name.py",
    data: { param: "hello" }
}).done(function(obj){
    alert(obj);
});
```

I want to get that request from my Python file and send a response to it - "world".

But, I can't use the library Requests.

Please help me do this without using the library Requests

Can also use a different way in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Please post your Python code and server configuration. Can you please tell us why you can't use `Requests`?

Comment: What are you getting as alert?

Comment: Using only specific libraries, not realy a big reason but just cant use it

Comment: Doesnt realy matter, obj will be a Json to proccess with javascript. The problem is the python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `requests` for that, you need an HTTP server.

Flask is a simple web framework, it embeds his own HTTP server.

Here is a basic example on how to answer an http request, using flask :

```
# main.py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return 'Hi'

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Install flask using pip:

```
python -m pip install flask
```

Then simply run your application development server using python :

```
python main.py
```

And visit :

```
http://[YOUR SERVER IP]/
and 
http://[YOUR SERVER IP]/hello
```